# Magento 2 How to uninstall attributes added by custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, attributes, custom, uninstall

So far I know that when uninstalling a custom module, it is possible to remove custom tables or columns added by custom module by using `uninstall.php` which extends `\Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface`. But how to remove custom attributes added by `InstallData.php` when uninstalling the module? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow this way : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/magento-2-uninstall-module

Comment: @Abdul I've read that post before. But it does not mention the method for removing attributes.

Comment: Do you mean values in a specific table?

Answer (score 12):

In a module, you would use the following code that utilizes dependency injection for uninstallation. It works equally well anywhere else, just be sure to inject the EavSetupFactory into the constructor and then utilize its methods to do the work.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Modulename\Setup {

    class Uninstall implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface
    {

        protected $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }



        public function uninstall(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

            $entityTypeId = 1; // Find these in the eav_entity_type table
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'attribute_code');

            $setup->endSetup();

        }
    }

}
```

Additionally, using this method will cause the eav attribute to properly remove itself from all tables, since they are linked using constraints.

BTW, I recommend using PHPStorm + xdebug. You will learn SO much about how all these things connect together.

Comment: What file and where does this go?

Comment: Its Uninstall.php. Its goes in the module setup folder. Check out the namespace. It always should match the pathname.

Comment: You can also use `Customer::ENTITY` or `Product::ENTITY` etc. instead of `1`  or `4`.
(`use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product; use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;`)

Comment: In addition to @JānisElmeris suggestion, consider defining your attribute name as a const in your setup file, so you don't need to use magic strings which can break your application if you decide to change a name and forget to change it in your uninstall script

Answer (score 3):

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer class instead of entity id like 1 and 2.

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) 
{
 $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

 public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface 
  $context)
   {
    $setup->startSetup();

   $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
   $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code_here');

  $setup->endSetup();
  }
}
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks brother your solution solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface::delete` for this.

Comment: True, but its implied he is building a custom module, so that means assuming the method for creation and deletion is programmatic.  Using the api is somewhat the wrong approach, however, you *could* backtrack your way from the AttributeRepositoryInterface to the class and methods that actually do the work.

Comment: @CarComp, Using the API is only one proper approach, if you interested in work of you module on new version of  Magento. Magento use BC policy only for api. And private implementation can be changed at any time without notification

Comment: I just re-read what I wrote.  I am not saying its the wrong approach for everyone, I meant just in relation to his question.  He was asking how to do it in php.

Comment: API - it interfaces with @api annotation, not Web API. Sorry if I something miss understudy