# Magento 2 class does not exist error backend

Tags: magento2, error, class

I'm trying to add another field to the customer create form.

The following code troughs an error in the backend. The error is:

> Class Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\String does not exist

or if I refresh the page it will change to:

> The requested component ("string") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

and back to the original error if i refresh again.

**Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace tivol\registrationExtra\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate", [
            "type" => "varchar",
            "backend" => "",
            "label" => "Sales associate",
            "input" => "string",
            "source" => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource',
            "visible" => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique" => false,
            "note" => "",

        ]);

        $salesAssociate = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate");

        $salesAssociate = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'salesAssociate');
        $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[] = "checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_create";
        /* $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit"; */
        $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_checkout";
        $salesAssociate->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $salesAssociate->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/layout/customer_registration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales_associate" template="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields::salesassociate.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/templates/salesassociate.phtml**

```
<legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('If you shop in-store who is your regular sales associate') ?></span>
</legend>


<div class="field">
    <label for="associate" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Associate') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <select name="regulation" id="associate" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Associate') ?>">
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'tivol_registrationExtra',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="tivol_registrationExtra" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Any ideas as to what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
"input"    => "string",
```

to the:

```
"input"    => "text",
```

because a component with name 'string' not exist.

Then reinstall your module.

**Note:** if on uninstall process your module does not delete the attribute `salesAssociate` programmatically you should do-it-yourself. Useful link - [Magento 2 How to uninstall attributes added by custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94222/magento-2-how-to-uninstall-attributes-added-by-custom-module)

#### Edit:

You can change input type right in the `eav_attribute` table, just find your attribute by the `attribute_code` (it should be `salesAssociate`) and set its `frontend_input` value as `text`. I didn't check this solution, but it should help.

#### Update:

You can just update your install class and reinstall the module. Add the line:

```
$customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate");
```

Before the:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "salesAssociate", [ ....
```

Remove the record about your module from the `setup_module` table and execute command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` in the magento root folder.

Comment: I followed the link but am unsure of where to put that file and what to call it?

Comment: @Mark I was glad to help. I have updated the answer just in case

Comment: now i just need to work out why it shows in the backend and not the front lol

Comment: So I can see it all now but it didn't save to the database for the customer any ideas?

Comment: @Mark Try to change the `<select name="regulation"` to the `<select name="salesAssociate"` because the name of your attribute is *salesAssociate*