# Uninstalling a module

Tags: magento2, module, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall a module (my own) that I've installed via composer using CLI with this command:

```
bin/magento module:uninstall -r [Namespace]_[Module]
```

Based on the answer [provided here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78251/146) by @RyanH I've created the `Setup/Uninstall.php` file that removes database related data of the module.

**This works perfectly but the uninstall procedure hangs.**

I've even left the script running over night and still the same result.
**The extension files are still there in the `vendor` module.**
I didn't touch the file permissions or owner.

What goes right:

- the database related data is removed
- the module name is removed from the table `setup_module`
- the module name is removed from `app/etc/config.php`.

What goes wrong:

- the module files are still there in the `vendor` folder.
- the console command does not finish.

Console output:

> You are about to remove code and/or database tables. Are you sure?[y/N]y
>   Enabling maintenance mode
>   You are removing data without a database backup.
>   Removing data of [Namespace]_[Module]
>   Removing [Namespace]_[Module] from module registry in database
>   Removing [Namespace]_[Module] from module list in deployment configuration
>   Removing code from Magento codebase:

After this it just hangs.

Is there anyway to finish the uninstall process, or at least debug it?

Comment: even I am facing the same issue . What is the solution for this . Do you have any idea

Comment: Not exactly. At one point it started working. I did a debug following the provided answer but did not find anything relevant.

Comment: ok, Thank you!!!  So how to uninstall the module

Comment: Run the command listed in the question

Comment: I am using that only but it stuck in  ,'Removing code from Magento codebase:'. After which it hangs

Comment: I had the same problem. But It worked at one point. I cannot explain it. My question was mostly about a way to debug this. Use the answer below and maybe you find out what the problem is.

Comment: ok, I will try debugging it. thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of the uninstall process were it hands can be found under `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ModuleUninstaller.php` :

```
public function uninstallCode(OutputInterface $output, array $modules)
{
    $output->writeln('<info>Removing code from Magento codebase:</info>');
    $packages = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo $packageInfo */
    $packageInfo = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfoFactory')->create();
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $packages[] = $packageInfo->getPackageName($module);
    }
    $this->remove->remove($packages);
}
```

Basically it lists the packages to remove and then run a `composer remove` command on those packages via `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Composer/Remove.php` :

```
public function remove(array $packages)
{
    $composerApplication = $this->composerApplicationFactory->create();

    return $composerApplication->runComposerCommand(
        [
            'command' => 'remove',
            'packages' => $packages
        ]
    );
}
```

You can find the `runComposerCommand` method in `vendor/magento/composer/src/MagentoComposerApplication.php` :

```
public function runComposerCommand(array $commandParams, $workingDir = null)
{
    $this->consoleApplication->resetComposer();

    if ($workingDir) {
        $commandParams[self::COMPOSER_WORKING_DIR] = $workingDir;
    } else {
        $commandParams[self::COMPOSER_WORKING_DIR] = dirname($this->composerJson);
    }

    $input = $this->consoleArrayInputFactory->create($commandParams);

    $exitCode = $this->consoleApplication->run($input, $this->consoleOutput);

    if ($exitCode) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            sprintf('Command "%s" failed: %s', $commandParams['command'], $this->consoleOutput->fetch())
        );
    }

    return $this->consoleOutput->fetch();
}
```

To me something happens along the way here and those functions are where you should start debugging.

Maybe you module `composer.json` file is missing or has an error.

Comment: my ccmposer file is there. This looks like a good place to start debugging. Thanks.

Comment: years later this has helped me understand why my uninstalls didnt work - I have to call composer like /usr/local/bin/ea-php72 ~/bin/composer/composer.phar and obviously the config is not up for it...

Answer (score 0):

when we run **bin/magento module: uninstall Module_Name** then it run composer update command also in back process that is not shown in cli.

When we run the composer update then it requires username and password that your magento marketplace account. if you have not then create :

To create authentication keys:

1. Log in to the [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/). If you don’t have an
   account, click Register.
2. Click your account name in the top-right of the page and select My
   Profile.
3. Click Access Keys in the Marketplace tab.

[image]

Run this command from your magento root directory `ln -s ~/.composer/auth.json var/composer_home/`  it will create symbolic link of your composer **auth.json**

When we run module: uninstall then it check auth.json in magento var folder or magento root directory.

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It requires the **Credentials** for the repository from where you have installed that module and it fails to find it and consequently it hangs up. So you have to mention the credentials first.

Please refer to the answer [over here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3544#issuecomment-729506080)

Answer (score 0):

apparently I ran

> **`composer remove vendor/module --ignore-platform-reqs`**

to uninstall the module that I had installed through composer.

Answer (score -1):

Composer stoped in load data from repo.magento.com

My auth.json was not correct. This decision helped me

```
config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>
```

[How to use the new repo.magento.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90983/how-to-use-the-new-repo-magento-com)