# magento 2 lost code for EAV attributes

Tags: magento2, module, eav

I use git and composer in my project. 
My flow:
1 Each module has its own git repository.
2 I use composer and install and update modules to my project

```
update composer.json
composer update <module name>
composer install
./bin/magento setup:upgrade
./bin/magento cache:flush
git commit ...
```

In Primary repository i store composer.lock and composer.json

When i checkout to other branch and call composer install some modules are deleted. But EAV attributes remain in the database and my Magento 2 store crashes.

How I can correct uninstall modules and his EAV attributes in my flow?

Comment: Please check this if your concern regarding uninstalling a module https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123544/uninstalling-a-module

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes module are not deleted correctly so you can manually remove them with the following steps

1-remove the folder `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`

2-drop module tables from database

3-remove the config settings.

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'
```

4-remove the module `<Vendor>_<Module>` from app/etc/config.php

5-remove the module `<Vendor>_<Module>` from table setup_module

```
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='<Vendor>_<Module>'
```

You can check here for more info
https://nwdthemes.com/2016/07/12/magento-2-uninstall-module/